# Modeling a simple dynamic workflow system (via data-driven dependency injection?)

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, dependency-injection, workflow

This is more of an architectural question than a request for code help. I think I came up with several solutions, but some of them feel bizarre. Hence, I'm looking for any kind of input.

### The Problem

Please keep in mind that the scenario below is purely hypothetical and is meant to illustrate the situation in a simple light.

Let's say I have a very simple workflow system which I would like to be configurable via an XML file. To keep our hypothetical example simple, let's call this workflow system a "wizard" with an arbitrary number of steps. There can be three possible steps, but they can be in any sequence and repeat any number of times.

Let's say the three possible wizard steps are:

- Information Screen
- Yes/No Choice Screen
- Choose Path Screen

These three screens will correspond to three classes, all inheriting from a common interface. We will define these as follows:

```
public interface IWizardScreen {
    void Show();
}

public class InformationScreen : IWizardScreen, IDisposable {
    // Implementation
}

public class YesNoChoiceScreen : IWizardScreen, IDisposable {
    // Implementation
}

public class ChoosePathScreen : IWizardScreen, IDisposable {
    // Implementation
}
```

Now, our wizard application will use these classes to present the end-user with a series of screens, stored in a list or queue like this:

```
public Queue<IWizardScreen> WorkflowScreens;
```

Lastly, the population of the sequence of these wizard screens (that `WorkflowScreens` object) will be driven by an external XML file, editable by an admin user. This XML file can look like this:

```
<workflow>
    <information-screen>
        <text>My first screen</text>
    </information-screen>
    <information-screen>
        <text>My second screen</text>
    </information-screen>
    <yesno-choice-screen var="mychoice">
        <text>My choice screen</text>
        <yes>2</yes>
        <no>1</no>
    </yesno-choice-screen>
    <choosepath-screen show-if="mychoice = '2'" />
    <information-screen show-if="mychoice = '1'>
        <text>My third screen</text>
    </information-screen>
</workflow>
```

This XML file needs to somehow be processed to achieve the same result as this:

```
public Queue<IWizardScreen> WorkflowScreens = new Queue<IWizardScreen>({
    new InformationScreen("My first screen"),
    new InformationScreen("My second screen"),
    new YesNoChoiceScreen("mychoice", "My choice screen", 2, 1),
    new ChoosePathScreen() { showIf = "mychoice = '2'" },
    new InformationScreen("My third screen") { showIf = "mychoice = '1'" }
});
```

Again, the exact specifications and constructors are irrelevant since this is a purely hypothetical example. In the end, what I need is for that XML file to be transformed into an array of objects, with as much extensibility (ideally, in theory, an admin user could just drop a new DLL with a new step into the 'bin' folder and add a new tag, and get a new screen as simple as that) and as little over-engineering as possible. (To clarify, the example in the preceding parentheses is also meant to serve purely as an example and is unrelated to this question; that specific functionality is not required, but showcases the degree of extensibility that I would prefer).

### Potential Solution 1: Run an XSLT Transform to feed into an IoC Container

This one seems as the most natural in this case, but also feels very over-engineered and bizarre. Basically, the XML file would be fed through an XSLT transform, to create an XML configuration file for a DI container (Castle, Spring.NET, whatever), which will then populate the objects.

### Potential Solution 2: Just parse the XML manually

This one feels easiest, but also least extensible and "clunky", where I'll need to create a lot of boilerplate code myself (for parsing XML, populating constructor parameters, possibly even some home-grown DI for the resolution of the actual components).

### Potential Solution 3: Ask Stackoverflow

The one I settled on for now :)

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing ̶ t̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶e̶l̶  Workflow Foundation. As an aside, why do you just `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` and be done with it?

Comment: @HighCore I've never used Workflow Foundation, but it feels huge and way overkill for something as simple as this (I could be wrong, though). Deserialization is possibly a good option, I actually thought of that last night but forgot about it this morning...

Answer (score 1):

As a third option (and one I've use many times) why not just code the workflows directly in an IOC container. Something like spring.net has everything you need to specify something like your wizard configuration using it''s own XML.  This will give you the same results as parsing the xml yourself, without the need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: That's one of the things I was initially thinking, too. But sometimes the people editing this will be non-developers, and it will be better to avoid having them work with the implementation directly (want to keep this as simple as possible).

Comment: You're right a spring configuration file isn't for the faint hearted, but neither is a simpler xml file really.  You could also consider an IOC with a fluid interface.  Your non-developers will use something that looks like a domain specific language.